# ошибки 502, 504 при парсинге

Tags: javascript, php, python, веб-программирование, web-scraping

При парсинге ресурса я иногда получаю ошибки 502 и 504.

Если просто открыть их с браузера, страницы работают.

---

так же, иногда мне несколько раз подряд отдаётся пустое тело в ответе(тоесть после запроса с пустым телом я делаю sleep на минуту, и опять получаю пустое тело)

---

инструменты парсинга: php + guzzle

---

P.S вопрос задался потому что на 1000 корректно распаршеных страниц приходится дюжина 502/504/empty.

Это интернет магазин, они не могут просто так отдать 504, иначе клиенты бы сьели с потрохами

Соответственно, что-то не так, но я не знаю что

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, это какие-то механизмы защиты могут такую подлянку делать, или в чём может быть загвоздка?

Comment: вам необходимо уточнить, какими инструментами для парсинга вы пользуетесь

Comment: @Alexandr поправил вопрос

Comment: `DoS`  это называется

Comment: @teran не совсем понимаю о чём вы. Расширьте пожалуйста ответ

Comment: что парсите то? Если запустите цикл запросов без пауз, то какой-нить простенький ресурс и сляжет от такого просто напросто.

Comment: @teran магазин.

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
При парсинге ресурса я иногда получаю ошибки 502 и 504.

Если просто открыть их с браузера, страницы работают.
```

Посмотрите какие заголовки вы используете при запросе с браузера и попробуйте скопировать их, так же если вы используете вебдрайвера, то попробуйте отключить опцию их определения

```
так же, иногда мне несколько раз подряд отдаётся пустое тело в ответе(тоесть после запроса с пустым телом я делаю sleep на минуту, и опять получаю пустое тело)
```

Пустое тело может отдаваться, когда мы работаем c динамическими страницами, которые формируются непосредственно в браузере, надо изучить сайт перед парсингом и определить как формируется контент(на сервере или на клиенте). Если html формируется на клиенте, попробуйте использовать selenium, который будет запускать js и формировать страницу.

```
Подскажите пожалуйста, это какие-то механизмы защиты могут такую подлянку делать, или в чём может быть загвоздка?
```

Да, возможно есть проверка на сервере например на определения браузера, если вы например отправляете запрос без user agent то сервер может его просто не обрабатывать. Нужно детальнее изучить сайт, чтоб понять в чем причина. Или может стоять ограничение на количество запросов в минуту/час/месяц. При превышении лимита ваш ip могут просто блочить и не отвечать на ваши запросы определенное время

Comment: всё делаю согласно этому. Собственно поэтому вопрос и возник: как, при том что 1000 страниц распарсилось, дюжина не распарсилась.

Comment: больше даже смущает то, что сам себе ресурс не может же отдать 504, иначе клиенты их бы сьели с потрохами(это магазин)

Comment: сервер просто напросто может не успевать отдавать ответы, или просто блокировать ваши запросы из-за ограничения количества вопросов с одного ip в настройках сервера. Может отдать 504, клиенты не запрашивают 1000 запросов в секунду, поэтому сервер просто блокирует таких 'клиентов', иначе несколько таких пользователей положили бы сервер.

Comment: если страница формируется на клиенте, то не силениум нужен, а смотреть что за аякс запросы подгружают данные, и их дублировать.

Comment: @teran бывает слишком много кода надо копировать, часто бывает миллион проверок на js c формированием cookies и прохождение каптч. Легче запустить Selenium  и подождать пока весь js отработает в webdriver.